# Problems in apache-nifi about unescapeJson

Tags: apache-nifi

I am using apache nifi to transform some data.

I have a string: *He didn’t say, \"S\\\"top!\"* ,and **unescapeJson()** give me this result: *He didn’t say, "S"top!"*

Is that right? My expected result is *He didn’t say, "S\"top!"*.

If the function was designed to do so,then how can i get my expected result.

example:

[input and output of ReplaceText](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzhjX.png)

[setting of ReplaceText](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dE49.jpg)

GetFile processor just read a file with content: **He didn’t say, \"S\\\"top!\"**

Comment: Can you share the exact expression language statement you are using and clarify how the escaped JSON is passed in?  It would be helpful to reproduce the issue.

Comment: thanks for your reply.I have edited my question and uploaded some screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround appears to be possible by changing the ReplaceText **Replacement Value** property to just `${'$1'}`.  In my sample, this produced the desired output, `He didn't say, "S\"top!"`.

I do not yet fully understand why, but I believe it is related to evaluating the output of the search as a regex for the replace, where the backslashes are evaluated before `unescapeJson()` is applied, so it ends up being redundant.  This does not happen if you set Replacement Value to just `$1`, for example.

---

**Update**

I had the order wrong above, the order of resolution is as follows:

1. Search returns: `He didn’t say, \"S\\\"top!\"`
2. Expression Language evaluates `${'$1':unescapeJson()}` to: `He didn’t say, "S\"top!"`
3. Replace result is: `He didn’t say, "S"top!"`

So unescapeJson() is working as expected, and the behavior you are not expecting is that the remaining backslash is lost in the replace as an artifact of [String::replaceAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

Comment: I found out a bit more, but the bottom line is probably to use something JSON-specific for JSON body content, like EvaluateJsonPath.